# FB messenger extension (web url button) and bot framework (source event) issue

Tags: botframework

We want to use Messenger Exentions (using web_url button) as explained in this article. 
https://blog.messengerdevelopers.com/using-the-webview-to-create-richer-bot-to-user-interactions-ed8a789523c6

We need this for context id and be able to save the preference and get back to the original chat thread.

When creating a button to open web_url with the param messenger_extensions: true, we are getting 400 (bad request). Example below.

We did all other white listing of domain and extension code in the public page. But at the moment we can't get the buttons to display.

We tried normal botbuilder card and it works but can't pass this messenger_extensions:true parameter.

Facebook documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/url

### Help?

var replyMessage = new builder.Message(session).text("Testing");

```
    replyMessage.sourceEvent({ 
        facebook:{
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "button",
                    "text":"Try the URL button!",
                    "buttons": [{
                        "type":"web_url",
                        "url":"https://www.messenger.com/",
                        "title":"URL Button",
                        "webview_height_ratio": "full",
                        "messenger_extensions": true,  
                        "fallback_url": "https://www.facebook.com/"                            

                    },
                    {
                        "type":"web_url",
                        "url":"https://www.messenger.com/",
                        "title":"URL Button",
                        "webview_height_ratio": "full",
                        "messenger_extensions": true,  
                        "fallback_url": "https://www.facebook.com/"                            

                    }]   
                }
            }
        }
    });

    session.send(replyMessage);
```

Comment: Ok, found the issue. We have to white list the URL (in this case https://www.messenger.com) in the facebook admin page. We were doing it through the code shown in one of these examples, but it wasnt' effective.  Did it through admin page and it was working.